# ¿Como puedo hacer que disminuya el texto si una palabra excede el tamaño del div?

Tags: css

Tengo un parrafo al que le he aplicado por css:

```
max-width:158px;
word-wrap: break-word
```

Actualmente como está no aumenta el tamaño del `div` (*que es lo deseado*)  me gustaría que si una palabra es demasiado larga y excede el tamaño se disminuya el texto entero para que la palabra no rompa y continue por debajo.

He probado con `font-size-adjust: 0.5` pero el texto no disminuye.

Comment: `font-size-adjust` es para ajustar el tamaño de las minúsculas en relación al de las mayúsculas, puesto que el `font-size` está basado en el tamaño de la fuente en mayúsculas y a veces esto resulta en fuentes ilegibles a bajos tamaños. Para ajustar el tamaño de manera dinámica no queda otra que usar javascript.

Comment: No entiendo, que es lo que quieres .- 1) Que el texto genere un salto de línea o 2) que el tamaño del texto disminuya para que entre en una sola línea??

Comment: Hola Tom, ¿te serviría una solución sin CSS?

Comment: @Yussef, entiendo que sería la opción 2. La 1 es la que actulamente ha implementado y no le sirve

Comment: @Marcos Lo de `continue por debajo.` es lo que me genera la duda

Comment: ¿Algo [así](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16346076/13419694)?